# Why is 1 cubic meter 1000 liters?

Tags: unit-of-measure

Can anyone explain why $1\ \mathrm{m}^3$ is $1000$ liters?

I just don't get it.

1 cubic meter is $1\times 1\times1$ meter. A cube. It has units $\mathrm{m}^3$.

A liter is liquid amount measurement. 1 liter of milk, 1 liter of water, etc.

Does that mean if I pump $1000$ liters of water they would take exactly $1$ cubic meter of space?

I can't wrap my head around.

Comment: Liters measure volume, just like cubic meters do. And yes, 1000 liters would take up the same volume as 1 cubic meter.

Comment: so is unit of measurement for liters `[m^3]`? 1 liter is 1/1000 of a cubic meter?

Comment: The liter is itself a unit of measurement, and $1000~ \mathrm l = 1~\mathrm m^3$.

Comment: But who invented that `1000l = 1m^3`? Is it arbitrary definition? Where does this definition come from?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litre

Comment: $1$ m is a reasonable standard of length, compared to the size of a man. $1\>{\rm m}^3$ is much more than a man can drink, therefore one had to invent a more handy unit for everyday use, but still coupled to the metric system. $1$ Liter serves this purpose well.

Comment: Seems to me that the Wikipedia article touches far too lightly on the history. The point is, roughly, that the revolutionaries, in a desire to make a completely reasonable system, based everything on the meter, which was to be (I think) $10^{-7}$ of the distance from the pole to the equator. From that all was to follow. Litre is, as many have said, a cubic decimeter, so the relation between litres and meters follows directly from that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 liter is, by definition, 1 cubic decimeter, where 1 decimeter is 1/10 meter.

So $1000\,\mathrm{l} = 1000\,\mathrm{dm^3} = 1000\,(1/10\,\mathrm{m})^3 = 1000/10^3\,\mathrm{m^3} = 1\,\mathrm{m^3}$.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how people came to define this?

Comment: Because it's convenient?

Comment: What came first? Liter or cubic decimeter?

Comment: @bodacydo: You should check out this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litre#Definition

Comment: Another way to look at it is 1 meter = 10 liters, so $1\times 1\times 1$ (cubic meter) is equal to $10 \times 10\times 10 = 1000$ cubic liters.

Comment: 1 meter can't be 10 liters because units don't match. 1 meter is `[m]`, 10 liters is `[m^3]`

Answer (score 1):

Originally:

- the metre was defined as 1/10,000,000th of the distance from the North pole to the equator at sea level;
- the litre was defined as 1/1,000th of a cubic metre;
- the kilogram was defined as the mass of a litre of water at freezing point.

Nowadays we have more precise standards, which don't rely on the density of water. But these relations are still very accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Density = weight per unit volume (water density = 1 Gram per 1 Cubic centimeter)

i.e Density X 1 Centimeter cube = 1 Gram of water

```
   1 X 1 cc = 1 Gram

   1 x 1 cc X 1000 = 1 Gram X 1000

    1000 cc = 1000 Gram = 1000 Milli liter = 1 Liter

    1000 cc x 1000 = 1 Liter x 1000

    1 Cubic meter =  1000 Liter
```